# Column Sizing in Scrollable Table

Tags: javascript, html, css

Here's some background info before I get to my question...I am implementing a JavaScript library for supporting HTML tables that have scrollable bodies and stationary headers.

**Requirements:**

1. The table layout must work the same as in a normal table; the column sizes should grow or shrink to fit the contents
2. Multi-row headers must be supported along with reasonable use of `colspan` and `rowspan` therein.
3. The library should work on virtually any table, provided that the table adheres to the structure prescribed by the ScrollTable library.
4. Support an arbitrary number of columns.
5. Support arbitrary formatting of the table cells (e.g., thickened column separators between column groups)

**Assumptions:**

1. The header has no more than 2 rows
2. A given cell in the header can use `colspan` or `rowspan`, but not both
3. Each logical column in the header table contains at least one cell that does not span multiple columns.
4. The cells in the body do not use `colspan` or `rowspan`

**How I implemented it:**

1. Separate the table into two tables: a table of header cells and a table of body cells
2. Wrap each table in a `<div>` and then both of those in one “ScrollTable” `<div>`

   - The div containing the body table is what facilitates the scrolling
   - The main `<div>` has `display: inline-block` to shrink to fit its contents
3. Use `table-layout: fixed` to allow for explicit column sizing
4. Use `box-sizing: border-box;` and `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` on the table cells to make column-sizing easier
5. Implement an `updateLayout` method:

   - Clear any explicit column widths to allow natural column sizing to occur in both tables
   - Loop over a representative set of cells from the header table and body table – one cell per column.
   - For each column, assign the bigger column width from the header or body table in both tables.

     - For the header table, assign the widths to the `<col>` elements if the table has them.  If the table doesn't have `<col>` elements, try to assign the widths to the cells in its first row.
     - For the body table, assign the widths to the cells in the table's first row

**Snags that I ran into but overcame:**

1. Retrieving the widths of the columns.

   - The ScrollTable needs to support multi-row headers.  And the cells therein might use `colspan` or `rowspan`.  So I can’t just grab an entire row of cells.
   - You can’t get a list of columns.  You can get a list of `<col>` elements if the table’s markup includes them, but you can’t use them to access the columns’ widths.
   - You *can* access a column’s width from cells within the column, though, so I solved the problem by writing a function that loops over the cells in the header and retrieves a representative set of cells, where the cells might not all come from the same row.
2. For tables with `table-layout: fixed`, the table and column widths are set by the widths of `<table>` and `<col>` elements or by the width of the first row of cells.  That’s it; cells in subsequent rows do not affect column widths.

   - This ultimately means that support for multi-row headers (which might use rowspan or colspan) can only be achieved by requiring the markup of ScrollTables that have multi-row headers to include a `<col>` element for every column in the header.

**Snags I have yet to overcome:**

When I assign a width to a `<col>` element, it doesn’t give quite the same width as when I assign that same width to a table cell.  And `box-sizing: border-box;` and `-moz-box-sizing: border-box;` appear to have no effect on `<col>` elements.

**Question:**

How can I ensure that the width I assign to the `<col>` elements gives the same rendered width as what I assign to the table cells?

Comment: Wow. You wrote so much but could have saved so much time by just sharing the code... ;)

Comment: @BenM Yeah, I know. :)  But it's 300+ lines of JavaScript and about 100 lines of CSS, not to mention the HTML...  Anyway, it really boils down to that one question.  I just wanted to provide some context.